# Prove $\dim(W/Im T)-\dim(\ker T/{\rm Im} S)+\dim\ker S=\dim W-\dim V+\dim U$ under these conditions...

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Question: Suppose $U,V,W$ are vector spaces over some field.  Let $S:U\rightarrow V$ and $T: V\rightarrow W$ be linear transformations such that $T\circ S$ is the zero map.  Prove $$\dim(W/Im T)-\dim(\ker T/{\rm Im} S)+\dim\ker S=\dim W-\dim V+\dim U$$

My Thoughts:  I suppose I want to show that $\dim W=\dim(W/{\rm Im} T)$, $\dim V=\dim(\ker T/{\rm Im} S)$, and $\dim U=\dim\ker S$.  I suppose I could start with a basis $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ for $S$ and extend to a basis for $U$, say $\{s_1,\dots,s_k,u_1,\dots,u_r\}$ such that $\dim S=k$ and $\dim U=k+r$.  I could use the same idea to get a basis for $T$ and extend to a basis for $V$, and to a basis for $W$, and then just try to show that the dimension on the LHS is equal to the dimension on the RHS.  However, I am having a bit of an issue handling the kernals, images, etc.  I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this, or if maybe I could tweak my argument to make things come out a bit nicer.  Or, am I just chasing the wrong idea.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: "I want to show that $\dim W = \dim(W / \text{Im} T)$" this won't necessarily be true; consider the case where $T$ is not the zero map while $S$ is the zero map.

Comment: Ah, okay, so that is where the zero map stuff comes in.  But, playing a game with bases and dimensions is still the best way?

Comment: Your thoughts are completely wrong. Maybe can happen that $\color{red}1-\color{blue}1+\color{green}2 = 2 =  \color{red}2-\color{blue}1+\color{green}1$.

Comment: @azif00 Right; I like angryavian's idea below (especially since I can already prove $\dim(U_2/U_1)=\dim(U_2)-\dim(U_1)$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $U_1$ is a subspace of $U_2$, show that $\dim(U_2/U_1) = \dim(U_2) - \dim(U_1)$. Thus,

- $\dim(W / \operatorname{Im} T) = \dim(W) - \dim(\operatorname{Im} T)$
- $\dim(\ker T / \operatorname{Im} S) = \dim(\ker T) - \dim(\operatorname{Im} S)$

The rank-nullity theorem implies the following.

- $\dim(\ker T) + \dim(\operatorname{Im} T) = \dim V$
- $\dim(\ker S) + \dim(\operatorname{Im} S) = \dim U$

Comment: Ah, okay, I see!  So, for this, does the zero map stuff come into play, or is it more of a way to "redirect" from my original method?

Comment: @User7238 The equation seems to hold without the assumption about the zero map. Is this part of a multi-part question? Maybe it is relevant elsewhere.

Comment: Nope, no multiple parts.  Interesting.  I wonder if whoever wrote the question maybe had an easier solution in mind, and so they wanted to eliminate it.

Comment: @User7238 In order to have $\operatorname{im}(S) \subseteq \ker(T)$ (so the quotient $\ker(T)/\operatorname{im}(S)$ makes sense) we need the assumption $T \circ S = 0$.

Comment: @azif00 Oops yes, I overlooked that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I think for the second bullet point, you should have $``-\dim(Im S)"$

Comment: @User7238 Thanks, fixed now